# Group Operators and Probability

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a question for my statistics class that reads: Calculate the probability of rolling 4 of a kind with a fair 4 sided die. Express this using group operator notation and as probabilities using mathematical operators.

I interpreted this to mean to calculate the probability of rolling a the same number 4 times using a 4 sided die.

I wrote the notation as:
P(rolling the same number 4x) = (rolling a 1 and rolling a 1 and rolling a 1 and rolling a 1) OR (rolling a 2 and rolling a 2 and rolling a 2 and rolling a 2) OR (rolling a 3 and rolling a 3 and rolling a 3 and rolling a 3) or (rolling a 4 and rolling a 4 and rolling a 4 and rolling a 4)

P(Ai) = (X1=1 ^ X2= 1 ^ X3= 1 ^ X4= 1) V (X1=2 ^ X2= 2 ^ X3= 2 ^ X4= 2) V (X1=3 ^ X2= 3 ^ X3= 3 ^ X4= 3) V (X1=4 ^ X2= 4 ^ X3= 4 ^ X4= 4)

I wrote it with the mathematical format using sigma; 4Sigma i=1 x 4sigma j=1 x 4sigma k=1 x 4sigma l=1 P(X1= i) V (X2=j) V (X3=k) V (X4= l)

but when I calculate this probability I get (4*4)x(1/4) which gives me 1.

When I calculate by hand as an independent event, I get 4*(1/4^4) which gives me the answer of 4/256 or 0.015.

I am not sure which mathematical format to use. Someone please help me understand.

Comment: The space has $4^4$ combinations so the probability of all $1$s is $1/{4^4}$. Can you see why I mention that?

Comment: You need only one kind of index, i.e. $x$. $P(X_1=x\cap X_2=x\cap X_3=x \cap X_4=x)$ $=\sum\limits_{x=1}^4 P(X_1=x)\cdot P(X_2=x)\cdot P(X_3=x)\cdot P(X_4=x)$

Comment: Does no reply means, that you are not interested in your own question? If yes, why you are asking?